# Attributed strings in Appcelerator and applying the @ symbol mid string

Tags: javascript, ios, appcelerator

I'm struggling a little bit with attributed strings in Appcelerator and was hoping for some assistance.

So, I have a couple of scenarios.

I use an API to retrieve user information, but the app needs to display said username with an @ in front of it and be in a different colour to the rest of the string. Now this is ok for the screens that have the username at the beginning, but unfortunately I can't get it to work mid string.

Here is the current code:

```
var attr = Ti.UI.createAttributedString({
                                        text: '@' + text,
                                        attributes: [{
                                            type: Ti.UI.ATTRIBUTE_FOREGROUND_COLOR,
                                            value: '#ff3333',
                                            range: [text.indexOf(userToHighlight), (userToHighlight).length+1]
                                        }]
                                    });

                                    var notificationMessage = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                                        attributedString: attr,
                                        left: 0,
                                        top: 5,
                                        font: {
                                            fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Light',
                                            fontSize: 13
                                        }
                                    });
```

And this is what the output should look like in the different scenarios....

1. @username likes your post
2. You are now friends with @username

So, the conditions for those strings are as follows....

1. the username and the @ should be in red, the rest of the string should be black
2. the username and the @ should be in red, the rest of the string should be black

Scenario 1 is ok, but scenario 2 currently looks like this...

@You are now friends with username

So the @ is at the beginning, the main question is how do I attach it to the username mid string?

The API returns the username and i've added that to a variable here:

```
var userToHighlight = json[i].participants[1].username;
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Simon

Answer (score 1):

Injecting a username into a string isn't that hard when using `String.format()`. A good tutorial can be found on [TiDev](http://www.tidev.io/2015/01/26/formatting-strings-the-correct-way-using-an-old-friend-printf/).

Basically:

```
var message = String.format('Welcome, %s! You are visitor number %d', forename, number);
```

In your case, make the original text with variables, and inject them later.

```
var text = "You are now friends with @%s";
var text = "@%s likes your post";
```

Then in attributed string:

```
text: String.format(text, userToHighlight)
```

Comment: my text variable is dynamic (from an API), so the strings will always be different, assume that can still be applied in the same way?

Comment: yes. If you provide the `%s` from the server that fixes it

Comment: Would i not need to provide every type of text response back with the %s included? So get the message from the API and then build the text variable with different positions for each username scenario. Hard to explain this really! Hoping i'm not confusing matters